# Can't get concurrency to work as I expect it

Tags: go

I am trying to understand why my code does not work, so I managed to recreate the problem in a simpler example.

I expected this code to output the string "broadcasted", but it does not output anything.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type hub struct {
    handle    chan []byte
    broadcast chan []byte
}

func (h *hub) init() {
    for {
        select {
        case m := <-h.handle:
            handler(m)
        case _ = <-h.broadcast:
            fmt.Println("broadcasted")
        }
    }
}

var socketHub = hub{
    handle:    make(chan []byte),
    broadcast: make(chan []byte),
}

func main() {

    go socketHub.init()

    m := []byte("this is the message")
    socketHub.handle <- m

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
}

func handler(m []byte) {
    // Do some stuff.
    socketHub.broadcast <- m
}
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `broadcast` channel is *unbuffered*. This means that:

1. You send the message to the `handle` channel: main goroutine blocks until...
2. In the goroutine, the `select` case gets the message...
3. And calls (in the goroutine) `handler`, which sends the message to the `broadcast` channel, blocking until...

And that's it: your child goroutine is blocking, waiting on itself to pick the message. Concurrently, your main goroutine sleeps, then reaches the end of `main`, exits and terminates the program.

You can 'solve' it in several ways:

- Make your `broadcast` channel buffered: this way, goroutine sends the message, which succeeds immediately, and returns in the `for` loop, selecting it back and printing as intended
- Make your `send` a (new) goroutine, either in `handler`, or by calling `go handler(m)` in your loop
- Have two different goroutines listen to `handler` and `broadcast`

Which one you choose depends on the exact problem you try to solve: in this tiny example, it's hard to find a 'best' one.